# Prove there exists an intersection when projecting a möbius band into a 2d plane.

Tags: general-topology

In a video of 3blue1brown he says that when projecting a mobius band into 2d plane, two points must intersect and I would like to know why this is true, but i dont know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the continuous projection were 1-1 then the image of the central loop of the Moebius band would be a Jordan curve in the plane, which by the Jordan curve theorem divides the plane into an inside and an outside regions. Thus the loop would have an inside and an outside in the Moebius band as well, but as we know they are "the same".